# Как интегрировать slick slider или swiper?

Tags: javascript, mysql, slick.js, слайдер, swiper

Как slick slider или swiper вместо текущего в вёрстке. Файл с текущим и описание прилагаю, картинки выгружаются из базы данных

```
<?php $gallery = explode(", ", $images); ?>
```

```
        <?php if (is_array($gallery)) : ?>

            <a class="image-link" href="<?php echo filter_var($gallery[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); ?>">
                <img class="imghead" src="<?php echo filter_var($gallery[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); ?>" alt="Image">
            </a>


            <?php if (count($gallery) > 1) : ?>
                <div class="gallery-controls">
                    <div id="prev-slide" class="arrow-prev">&#10094;</div>
                    <div id="next-slide" class="arrow-next">&#10095;</div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. неизвестно в каком виде лежат изображения в массиве, возможно код для вставки урла нужно поправить. Ну и сами ресурсы слайдера должны быть корректно подключены к странице.

```
<div class="slider single-item">
  <?php if (is_array($gallery)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($gallery as $item) : ?>
      <div class="item-slide">
        <a class="image-link" href="">
          <img class="imghead" src="<?php echo filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); ?>" alt="Image">
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
  $('.single-item').slick();
</script>
```

Comment: Не получилось, если скину файл посмотришь ?

Comment: Опишите подробнее что вы делаете и что не получается.

Comment: Подключил по инструкции стили и скрипты вместе с этим кодом, но вместо слайдера только картинки столбиком

Comment: В инспекторе кода в браузере нет ошибок по подключениям стилей и скриптов?

Comment: И не забудьте инициализировать сам слайдер (код выше обновил)